# Есть ли у Flyway генерация файла миграций

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, flyway

Есть ли у flyway какая то команда для генерации файла миграции по моделям. Или они только вручную пишутся?
Например, я ввожу команду, и у меня появляется сгенерированная миграция. Которую в дальнейшем я уже могу применять к бд.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway